# Associating two models in Sequelize 1 to many, but with limitations?

Tags: database-design, sequelize.js

I am currently building a database with a Project model, and a Task model using Sequelize and Postgres. A **project** can have any number of **tasks**, so I have the **projectId** as a column on the **task** table. There are different types of tasks, an **Original**, a **Revision** or an **Install Review**.

How would I limit it so that the given project can only have 1 Task with status Original, and any new tasks created are forced to be a Revision?

Would this be something I can control at the actual database level in Sequelize, or would the controller for creating tasks need to check if the given project already has a task with status Original?

An invoicing system will rely on this structure where an Original costs more than a Revision, so I thought I'd bounce the idea off people with more experience.

I can post some code if needed. I guess this is more of a philosophy or "best practice" question.

Comment: Some will say that the database stores information, and the code takes care of the business logic.  Others will argue that you should enforce vital business rules into the model to avoid data corruption.  Some do both.  All 3 scenarios can be valid, and can be implemented.

Comment: This is good insight, thank you very much. I will do some paper planning before proceeding.